# Flex DateFormat validation in java

Tags: apache-flex, date-formatting

I have a XLSX file which contain 2 columns 1 being a formatted date, time or datetime field and other being the relavant format string of type FLEX. So this file contains Flex date format string with formatted value. This files can be contain more than one thousand such combination records. 
Eg:

> M/D/YYYY L:NN:SS A  --------- 7/4/1958 11:34:30 AM
>
> MM/DD/YYYY  ------------------- 07/13/2009
>
> L:NN:SS A  -----------------------             1:24:20 PM

What i need to know is, is there anyway that i can validate this given date , time or date time values at right side are formmated according to given FLEX format in the left side.
Important thing is , **this need to be happened in java side**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

Boolean function checkValidity(String date, String flexFormat)
    String s = date;
    String str = flexFormat;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat();
    try {

        String f = buildFormatString(str);
        formatter.applyPattern(f);

        Date d = formatter.parse(s);
        System.out.println(d);
        String nd = formatter.format(d);
        if(nd.compareTo(s) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //This means the format was wrong 
    }
    return false;
}

//This function changes the Flex date format to the java date format
//It will not work if the Flex format has text other than the recognised formatting characters.
private static String buildFormatString(String str) {
//      The mask pattern. 
//      You compose a pattern String using specific uppercase letters, for example: YYYY/MM.
//
//      The DateFormatter pattern String can contain other text in addition to pattern letters. To form a valid pattern String, you only need one pattern letter.
//
//      The following table describes the valid pattern letters:
//
//      Pattern letter Description 
//      Y Year. If the number of pattern letters is two, the year is truncated to two digits; otherwise, it appears as four digits. The year can be zero-padded, as the third example shows in the following set of examples: 
//      YY = 05 
//      YYYY = 2005 
//      YYYYY = 02005 

        String jFormat = str;
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("Y", "y");

//       
//      M Month in year. The format depends on the following criteria: 
//      If the number of pattern letters is one, the format is interpreted as numeric in one or two digits. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is two, the format is interpreted as numeric in two digits. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is three, the format is interpreted as short text. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is four, the format is interpreted as full text. 
//      Examples: 
//      M = 7 
//      MM= 07 
//      MMM=Jul 
//      MMMM= July 


//       
//      D Day in month. While a single-letter pattern string for day is valid, you typically use a two-letter pattern string. 
//      Examples:
//
//      D=4 
//      DD=04 
//      DD=10 

        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("D", "d");

//       
//      E Day in week. The format depends on the following criteria: 
//      If the number of pattern letters is one, the format is interpreted as numeric in one or two digits. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is two, the format is interpreted as numeric in two digits. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is three, the format is interpreted as short text. 
//      If the number of pattern letters is four, the format is interpreted as full text. 
//      Examples: 
//      E = 1 
//      EE = 01 
//      EEE = Mon 
//      EEEE = Monday 



//       
//      A am/pm indicator. 

        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("A", "a");

//      H Hour in day (1-24). 
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("H", "k");


//      J Hour in day (0-23). 
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("J", "H");


//      K Hour in am/pm (0-11). 
        //jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("K", "K");

//      L Hour in am/pm (1-12).
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("L", "h");

//      N Minute in hour.
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("N", "m");

//      Examples:
//
//      N = 3 
//      NN = 03 
//       
//      S Second in minute. 
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("S", "s");

//      Example:
//
//      SS = 30 
//       
//      Q Millisecond in second
        jFormat = jFormat.replaceAll("Q", "S");

//      Example:
//
//      QQ = 78 
//      QQQ = 078 
//       
//      Other text You can add other text into the pattern string to further format the string. You can use punctuation, numbers, and all lowercase letters. You should avoid uppercase letters because they may be interpreted as pattern letters. 
//      Example:
//
//      EEEE, MMM. D, YYYY at L:NN:QQQ A = Tuesday, Sept. 8, 2005 at 1:26:012 PM 
//       
//
//      Language Version:
//      3.0
//      Player Version:
//      Flash 9, AIR 1.1
//      Product Version:
//      Flex 3
        return jFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems fullfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a formatter and parse the string into a date.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

String s = "7/4/1958 11:34:30 AM";
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat();
try {
    Date d = formatter.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //This means the format was wrong 
}
```

Comment: Thx, what i need to know is whether the given String is formtted according to the format given in the file,

Comment: I doubt it. You need flex (or the flex formatting code) to check for that

Comment: See the patterns and the logic for the format string here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc364-70b5c6d212c98ca85e2-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf648c2-7ff9

Comment: you are going to have to parse the flex format string and then check the value. Just checking if the formatted value is valid, however, is a matter of parsing it.